# Mongoose find with some undefined fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to understand the behaviour of passing an object to `findOne` when some of the fields are undefined. Even stepping through the nodejs code I don't see it ever directly manipulate undefined fields, but it seems to.

Suppose I have a model like

```
_id: object id
relationA: object id
relationB: object id
```

If I do

```
mymodel.findOne({relationA: id, relationB: undefined})
```

It will not return results where it satisfies `relationA: id`. I *thought* it would just ignore `relationB` because it is undefined, but I can't tell what it does instead.

Does it

1. Convert this to null?
2. Convert this to `{$exists: false}`?
3. Is it only special when it is an ObjectId

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing an object with key/values to the `findOne` function, you are passing a [query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/).
The mongoDb engine search for documents that are matching you query criteria, that is, documents where `relationA` equals to the value of `id` AND `relationB` **is `undefined`** (or `Null`, for that matter).
If you only want to match documents that have `relationA` equal to some value, remove the `relationB` part: `mymodel.findOne({relationA: id}`.